# How to handle UIImage with TapGestureRecognizer in rotating

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a label and UIImage layout as below.

LabelMonth ImgArrowDown

This LabelMonth has TapGestureRecognizer as below.

When user tap on the LabelMonth, the ImageArrowDown will rotate 360 so that it look Pointing Up.

**Problem:**

- When user tap the LabelMonth again, how to rotate the ImageArrowDown back to its ORIGINAL Position which mean the Arrow in pointing down?

viewDidLoad(){

```
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:
        #selector(HandleImgRotation))

    LabelMonth.isUserInteractionEnabled = true LabelMonth.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    }




    func HandleImgRotation(_sender:AnyObject){

    UIView.animate(withDuration:1.0, animations: ({self.imgArrowDown.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.radian(degree:360))
                          }))

    }



    func radian(degrees:Double) -> CGFloat{

    return CGFloat(degrees * .pi/degrees) 

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the following method should resolve your problem...

```
var rotated = false

func HandleImgRotation() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            if !self.rotated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration:1.0, animations: ({
                    ImgArrowDown.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 0.999) )
                    self.rotated = true
                }))
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration:1.0, animations: ({
                    ImgArrowDown.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    self.rotated = false
                }))
            }
        }
    }
```